# Qt Creator cannot set debugger for 64bit (despite installed and properly detected)

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2013, qt-creator

My setup consists of Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 and Qt 5.5.1. For the Debugger(s) I use CDB from the Windows SDK. I use both toolchains, 32bit and 64bit.

To clean up my machine, I recently deinstalled all Microsoft Visual Studio stuff including the debuggers. Now, after the new installation of all the tools, I am not able to set up the 64bit debugger anymore. The interesting thing is that both debuggers are correctly autodetected under the Debuggers tab `Tools -> Options -> Debuggers`.

Under the `Kits` tab, I see the yellow triangle on the 64bit entry. I also see that `None` is selected in the Debugger line. But I am not able to change this setting because it is deactivated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution to this problem by editing a Qt Creator configuration file manually. The file `toolchains.xml` is found here in Windows 7:

```
%APPDATA%\Roaming\QtProject\qtcreator
```

**Additional Note:**
Since the original post, I've updated to Visual Studio 2015 Express and Qt 5.6. This environment is a lot simpler to set up than VS2013.